# How do I check if an int is divisible by another int? Using c#, Following specified the conditions

Tags: c#, math

Write a method:

```
public int IsXDivisibleByY(int X, int Y) { .. }
```

That meets the following conditions:

1. Method returns 1, if X can be divided by Y without a remainder.
2. Method returns 0, if X can't be divided by Y without a remainder.
3. Solution **MUSN'T** include any conditional checks (if condition, equality operators, the ternary and null-coalescing operators, etc.).
4. Solution **MUSN'T** include any exception handling (try-catch-finally)
5. It must be taken into account that both parameters could be given all range of the parameter type.

The answer is going to be considered wrong if any of the aforementioned conditions is not met.-

Using C#.

Comment: You should read the FAQ [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Why are you returning `int` and not `bool`?

Comment: Is it a puzzle? I like "etc." part in condition 3, it basically prevents you from using any sort of branching (4 is not needed) thus making solution impossible.

Comment: Yes, it's a challenge

Comment: I dont know "Why neeed return int and not bool"

Comment: @Sinatr you still can use bitwise operators and shifting bits, I think it can have solution.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev do you have any idea?

Comment: I have some, but number 5 ruins it all. I don't understand now how to rule out division by zero.

Comment: "what have you tried" - we're not a code-writing service; hint: "mod"

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev By mathematical definition, X mod Y when Y is zero is undefined, which means that it would not be possible to correctly return 0 or 1 as the answer (according to points 1 and 2 of the requirement). In that case, one correct solution is to not return anything, by throwing an exception.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev can you shared the code?

Comment: Ok, if division by zero exception is possible then I will post answer.

Comment: Yes, please post the answer

Comment: `return Convert.ToInt32(!Convert.ToBoolean(X % Y));`

Comment: @Charlieface it's elegant, but I think restrictions are applied to called methods too)

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev: loopholes are loopholes. Exercises like these are dumb to begin with, as the examiner already has the answer in mind and somehow wants you to stumble over it. All is fair in love, war and dumb puzzles like this. Personally I'd look at leveraging floating-point (`x % (y + double.Epsilon)` sounds promising, though I haven't got a full solution).

Comment: @Charlieface you cant use operator like "!"

Comment: You didn't say that? How about `return unchecked((-Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToBoolean(X % Y))) + 1);`

Comment: I dont know if can use Convert, but it's a solution

Comment: @Charlieface when you divide by zero throw exception

Comment: Correct, that is what you are supposed to do. `5 / 0` doesn't yes have a remainder or not have a remainder, it is simply undefined.

Comment: @Charlieface your solution return unchecked((-Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToBoolean(X % Y))) + 1), not work because "Method returns 1, if X can be divided by Y without a remainder." and return 0

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @Charlieface, No no no, I'm wrong, your method work to dont throw exception you can convert Y and X to double

Comment: @Paulo Alexandre so you sure or not is violating rules is acceptable in methods that you call? Cause I'm pretty sure all this Convert method are violating them, if I was creating this puzzle, I would definitely prohibit such things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution, it uses only modulus and bit operations (it also uses conditional checks in for loop, but it can be easily replaced by 32 explicit code blocks, I will omit this for better looking).

```
public int IsXDivisibleByY(int X, int Y)
{
    var mod = (int)((float) X % (float) Y);
    var accum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        accum = accum | (mod & 1);
        mod = mod >> 1;
    }

    return accum ^ 1;
}
```

Comment: how can I replaced by 32 explicit code blocks? I have no ideia =(

Comment: I think it can be 31, sign bit is insignificant in this case. Just repeat this 31 times instead of loop: `accum = accum | (mod & 1); mod = mod >> 1;`

Comment: but, Why need repeat 31 times? I can't understand that

Comment: You have to do it to roll all bits of resulting modulus. But I think you better go with Charlieface solution, this bitwise stuff can be hard for you to understand.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsevI dont if Charlieface not is violating rules, can you convert X and Y to double and try to use your solution? because when division by zero with double not happens expcetion

Comment: @Paulo Alexandre Edited solution, it returns 0 (can't be divided) if Y is 0. In this case all 32 bits matters, including sign.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I think we have to shift bit 31 times only, in the corrected code last right shift anyways not considered calculating the accum

Comment: @Kishor Yes 31 is enough, I've mentioned that in previous comments.